# Docker: Change entrypoint to custom script that calls original endpoint

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I try to execute a script before the original entrypoint of the `mysql/mysql-server` docker image.

What I tried so far was to add

```
entrypoint: ["/custom-entrypoint.sh"]
```

to the docker-compose file. The content of the `custom-entrypoint.sh` is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# TODO: Add important stuff

/entrypoint.sh
```

But now whenever I start the container it exits immediately. Why doesn't the call to /entrypoint.sh keep it running indefinitely? It is the original entrypoint, adding it explicitly to the docker-compose results in the default behavior.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the original image have a CMD defined as well? When you set a new ENTRYPOINT, you overwrite both the ENTRYPOINT and the CMD.

Comment: Try to view the logs of your mysql container to see what went wrong using this command: docker logs your-container-id

Comment: @HansKilian Yes, it does. I just tried to explicitly added the CMD, it did not work

Comment: @Hakro The logs do not contain anything useful, just `2023-04-14 14:00:34 [Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.32-1.2.11-server`. I guess that just means the original entrypoint is called as expected.

Comment: @HansKilian Ah, I've got it! I simply added the CMD at the end of my custom entrypoint script and now it works :) Thanks for the advice!